# TYPO3 EXT: DISQUS comment plugin for tx_news

Tags: typo3, disqus, typo3-6.1.x

I'm running TYPO3 v. 6.1 with FLUID/EXTBASE.

I have installed the News (tx_news) plugin and it's running fine, now i need a comment plugin and have looked at the Disqus, I can see that I installe the EXT: Typo3 Blog and add that to my detail view page for the tx_news and then add the Disqus as master, that overwrite typo3 blog.

My question is now, the comment count for a news, can i pull that out to the list view page for the news, so I can show the comment at that level.

If yes, how do I do that ?

Comment: Please name the extensions also by their keys and try to have a better syntax. It is totally unclear what you mean with "have looked at the Disqus, I can see that I installe the EXT: Typo3 Blog and add that to my detail view page for the tx_news and then add the Disqus as master, that overwrite typo3 blog.".

Comment: Just to clarify for others reading this question is referring to the news extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tx_news have the DISQUS ViewHelper included. Put this in your tx_news detail.template

```
 <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
  <n:social.disqus newsItem="{newsItem}"
      shortName="demo123"
      link="{n:link(newsItem:newsItem,settings:settings,uriOnly:1)}" />
```

Comment: The original question was how to show the comment count on the list page... can someone please answer that for TYPO3 and the news extension? Here's some docs from Disqus but don't know if there's more tricky stuff for our situation... https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624-adding-comment-count-links-to-your-home-page

Answer (score 0):

Disqus and TYPO3 are two different worlds. As I see it, the only way to isolate the comment count from the rest of the iframe would be via an API from disqus. Check with them if they offer something that returns your comment count when telling them the URL.